# JsonP with CakePHP

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, jsonp, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a CakePHP 2.x app and trying to implement JSONP. It's my first time, so I don't know how can I do this:

```
$(function(){
 $.getJSON("https://www.example.com/myweb/api/getjsonp&jsoncallback=?",
 function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
     );

        });
```

Controller:

```
public function getjsonp(){

$id = $this->Auth->user('idUser');
$messages = $this->Contact->getMessages($id);


$totalmessages = json_encode($messages);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $totalmessages . ')';
```

}

The code isn't working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you haven't open this in php 
try add this code at the top of php file

> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: what is this actually ? i am working on a Cakephp  so is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not rendering the correct layout/view. See [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) on using Json and Xml views.

**Steps:**

1. Add `Router::parseExtensions('json');` to your `router.php` file.
2. Load `RequestHandlerComponent` in your `(App)Controller`.
3. Create a `View` (named `app/View/Api/json/getjsonp.ctp`).
4. Fill `View` with:

   ```
   <?php
   $totalmessages = json_encode($messages);
   echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $totalmessages . ')';
   ```
5. Pass `$messages` from controller like this:

   ```
   public function getjsonp() {
     $id = $this->Auth->user('idUser');
     $messages = $this->Contact->getMessages($id);

     $this->set(compact('messages'));
   }
   ```
6. Change url from:

   `https://www.site.com/myweb/api/getjsonp&jsoncallback=?`

   to

   `https://www.site.com/myweb/api/getjsonp.json&jsoncallback=?`.

   Note the **`.json`**.

Comment: i didnt get the documnentation ... there is not any example there ..only explanation in plain english

Comment: not working ... when i typed the url in the browser .. it cant find the class

Comment: Did you add `Router::parseExtensions('json')`?

Comment: yup i have added ... when i try the url of my code  which i have written in my question into the browser .. i can see the result .bot not in console tab in firebug ... but your code is not coding.it is not going to the correct url